# Problem booting Server after doing apt-get update apt-get upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2

I have only been able to get my server to boot using older kernel and have to be at the machine for startup /reboot to get 14.04.

I tried boot-repair here is one text file saved - thought I had another but that one is not there. http://paste.ubuntu.com/17593608/

I am currently still very much a novice.

I have upgraded to 16.04 and the boot seems to be working  now.

Comment: +1 for putting that is paste bin! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.